# How to make Specific permssions for roles

Tags: webform-civicrm, permissions, civicrm-home, roles

I am using civicrm as my main source of managing my documents and all. What I do want is that I have a sales team that I don't want to show the specific pages or tabs. I already installed the role plugin but I want to make custom permissions. Can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you tried https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/custompermissions

Comment: welceom. what 'role plugin'? is this Drupal or WP? "webform" is drupal. "plugin" is wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The answer varies depending on the tabs and pages we're talking about, so additional context would be helpful.

However, if it's acceptable to hide but not disallow access to someone who's specifically trying to bypass your restrictions, the [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) extension allows customizing who sees which tabs on a per-group basis (CiviCRM groups, that is).